# Difference between a vector space and an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I'm new to the subject of algebras and I would like to get a better understanding of what they are exactly. Am I right to say the follwing:

```
Algebras over a field are basically vector spaces over a field 
where there is a multiplication defined between vectors.
```

Could someone say that they agree with me on this, or say way I am wrong to think this is true?

Comment: Not just a multiplication, but a mutiplcation that satisfies the ring axioms.

Comment: ..and compatibility: if $\;\Bbb A\;$ is the algebra over the field $\;\Bbb F\;$ , then it must be that $\;(ax)\cdot(by)=(ab)(xy)\;,\;\forall a,b,\in\Bbb F\;,\;\;\forall x,y\in \Bbb A$

Comment: Meaning the tuple $(\mathbb{A},1,*)$ where * is said multiplication forms a ring.... Correct?

Comment: Almost. Generally, we do not require that algebra multiplication be associative, while we do require this for rings. Also, algebras needn't be unitary, and (depending on your context) we usually require rings to be unitary.